# Definite Article and no Article with Animal Groups

Tags: articles, definite-articles, collective-nouns, animals

I've encountered two sentences:

> **—** Dogs make good family pets.

and

> The main source of food for **the** Hippo is **the** short grass.

My question is:
*Why do we use the plural form of 'dogs' with no article in the first example sentence and the singular form of 'Hippo' with the definite article in the second one?*

`Are there any rules concerning the use of articles with animal groups/species?`

Comment: It's not determined by the species being discussed. For example, we also say, "The dog is man's best friend."

Comment: **@ThePhoton** These sentences were found in a test paper, in an exercise that asked for correcting the mistakes. The sentence "**The** dog makes a good family pet" was supposed to be corrected into "Dogs make good family pets". Does the initial sentence really sound ungrammatical?

Comment: I agree that 'Dogs' sounds better in this instance, but I don't think 'the dog' is an error. It's a matter of style, not grammar. Maybe somebody with more knowledge can give an actual explanation instead of just "it sounds better to me", which is all I've got.

Comment: The dog/the hippo basically refer to the family of creatures that are called "dog/hippo". "The hippo" is rather formal as there are only two members, whereas "the dog" has many members, and some of them are not good pets, e.g. the wolf. In "The dog is a good pet", "dog is uncountable as it is a name/label/proper noun. The definite article is often placed before a class name designate it as a class noun: "The apple came from Kazakhstan."

Comment: _Ostrich is rather pleasant, but needs to be well roasted._ _The Ostrich is a rather silly bird._ _Ostriches make good pets._ Undefined individual (no article). Defined species (definite article). Collective noun (no article).